# angular clearing object after pushing to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have the following object:

```
 $scope.post = {user_id: $sessionStorage.user.user.id};
```

with this i have the following:

```
<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="post.text" style="overflow:scroll;height:150px;max-height:150px"></textarea>
```

On submit i want to do the following action:

```
    $scope.addPost = function () {
    $http.post(api.getUrl('post', null),
        {
            post: $scope.post
        }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.post.id = response;
            $scope.posts.push($scope.post);
        });

    $scope.post = {};
}
```

However when i clear `$scope.post` because of the databinding the post is empty. So my question is how can i avoid this?

Comment: What are you trying to do--make sure that the text of the post itself isn't cleared?  If that's the issue, why don't you simply not set `$scope.post = {}`, since that's what's clearing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of asynchronous nature of Ajax call - your `$scope.post = {};` is executed earlier than success / error callbacks.
You should do clearing `$scope.post` inside the callback, not outside.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy using `angular.copy()` which will return a new object with no references to the original.

This also removes any hashkeys that angular scope has added to the object which can be problematic when server sees unrecognized keys

```
$scope.addPost = function () {
 var postData = angular.copy($scope.post);
    $http.post(api.getUrl('post', null),
    {
        post: postData
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.post.id = response;
        $scope.posts.push(postData);
        $scope.post = {}; //wait for success to clear
    });    
}
```

As already noted should wait for success to clear the live version